# How to set timeout

Tags: python, shell, executable

I am using a bash executable to run a python script in a loop

Sometimes the browser (run by the python script) will stop loading and stop working for hours until I manually come and close the window which will cause the executable to re-run the python script. How can I do this automatically? If no new line is shown in the terminal for 2 mins, then quit python code and run it again.

This is what I have right now:

```
while true ; do 
     python3 /Users/Name/Desktop/pythoncode.py
done
```

It will run the code in a loop. Now I want it to close the code and run it again if no line is outputted in the terminal for 2 mins (the python script shows its progress in the terminal)

Thanks and happy new year

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60738749/timeout-a-bash-script-when-there-is-no-output-for-a-while this looks promising

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Also see [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).
It appears that you didn't bother to search as much as "Python timeout", so this question is premature.

Comment: I did do lots of searching before posting this question. I believe you are misunderstanding the question. I do not want it to timeout after 2 min if pythoncode.py outputs to stdout. if it does it should run forever and not be timedout

Comment: @Prune I want to terminate a python script if and only if it doesn’t output anything to the terminal in 2 min. Else loop forever

Comment: I think you misunderstand the solution path.  The timeout logic still applies.  You have to set a process to detect output, and another to timeout after 2 minutes.  If the first one receives any output, then it kills the timeout process.  If the timeout process reaches its 2-minute limit, then it terminates the job.  Your question doesn't show an attempt at either process, although you've described the functionality.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem should be handled in the pythoncode.py.You can detect whether there was a change in the last 2 minutes by using a setInterval method and increase a counter for every action that is taken by the code.
If it hasn't change the last 2 minutes, you can close it. The other script will run it again.

[Python Equivalent of setInterval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697039/python-equivalent-of-setinterval)

In the other python file which will run the script, you can use os.system()

[Run python script only if it's not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968080/run-python-script-only-if-its-not-running)

Comment: What is this? A mixture of bash and python? Even if it is pseudocode, it still does not answer the question which wants to rerun the script only if there is no output for 2 minutes.

Comment: You are right, I didn't understand it properly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this. Sorry can't upvote since less than 15 reputation. Haha. Don't know why it has -1 upvotes. Seems very helpful. Thanks again : )

Comment: In summary, I want to terminate a python script if it doesn’t output anything to the terminal in 2 min